# How to dynamically fill column values based on other column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Imagine you have the following df:

```
d = {'taxrate#1': [0.21, np.nan, np.nan], 'taxrate#2': [0.0, np.nan, np.nan]}
colstbf = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
colstbf

    taxrate#1   taxrate#2
0   0.21          0.0
3   NaN           NaN
5   NaN           NaN
```

And another df:

```
d = {'btw-percentage#1': [0.21, 0.21, 0], 'btw-percentage#2': [0.06, np.nan, 0.21]}
colsfilling = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
colsfilling


btw-percentage#1    btw-percentage#2
0   0.21            0.06
1   0.21            NaN
2   0.00            0.21
```

I want to fill the df with other values of another df when the values in the df are NaN.

However, because the taxrate items may be large (10 or bigger depending on document) I want to do this dynamically.

So I've tried the following:

```
cols_to_check = []
cols_to_check = colstbf.filter(regex = 'taxrate').columns
colstbf['is_na'] = colstbf[cols_to_check].isnull().apply(lambda x: all(x), axis=1)

colstbf = np.where(df['is_na'] == True, colstbf, df['taxrate#1'])
```

AND:

```
colsfinal = colstbf.fillna(colsfilling)
```

However, the above is not working..

desired output:

```
    taxrate#1   taxrate#2
0   0.21          0.0
3   0.21          NaN
5   0.00          0.21


colstbf = df.filter(like='taxrate')
colsfilling = dfresult.filter(like='btw-percent').astype(float)
colsfilling = colsfilling/100
colsfilling.columns = colstbf.columns
colstbf.combine_first(colsfilling)
df = df.join(colstbf, lsuffix='_left')
df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='_left')))]
df
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`pandas.DataFrame.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) by setting `overwrite` argument.

**overwrite** bool, default True How to handle non-NA values for overlapping keys:

- True: overwrite original DataFrame’s values with values from other.
- False: only update values that are NA in the original DataFrame.

```py
colstbf.update(colsfilling.rename(columns=dict(zip(colsfilling.columns, colstbf.columns))), overwrite=False)
```

```
print(colstbf)

   taxrate#1  taxrate#2
0       0.21       0.00
1       0.21        NaN
2       0.00       0.21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`df.combine_first`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) here.

```
colsfilling.columns = colstbf.columns
colstbf.combine_first(colsfilling)

  taxrate#1  taxrate#2
0       0.21       0.00
1       0.21        NaN
2       0.00       0.21
```